# Calculate square of value using NSExpression?

Tags: objective-c, expression

```
NSString *formul=@"3^2";
NSExpression *e = [NSExpression expressionWithFormat:formul];
int result = [[e expressionValueWithObject:nil context:nil] intValue];
NSLog(@"formule:%d", result);
```

I am trying to calculate (a+b)^2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ** instead of ^

```
NSString *formul=@"3 ** 2";
NSExpression *e = [NSExpression expressionWithFormat:formul];
int result = [[e expressionValueWithObject:nil context:nil] intValue];
NSLog(@"formule:%d", result);
```

But beware Foundation's power function is left associative (which is wrong). See Dave Delong's post.

http://funwithobjc.tumblr.com/post/6196535272/parsing-mathematical-expressions

Comment: Have an upvote for your 2013 comment, it helped me :)

Answer (score 1):

Replace the code above with:

```
NSString *formul=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.f",pow(2,4)];
NSExpression *e = [NSExpression expressionWithFormat:formul];
int result = [[e expressionValueWithObject:nil context:nil] intValue];
NSLog(@"formule:%d", result);
```

Comment: In this above code am use (a+b)^2 to calculate the result using NSExpression how to do?

Answer (score 1):

```
NSNumber *number1 = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:2];        
NSNumber *number2 = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:4];

NSString *strSqr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@",number1,@"+",number2];

NSExpression *arrayExpression = [NSExpression expressionForConstantValue: number1];

NSArray *arrNum=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSExpression expressionWithFormat:strSqr],arrayExpression,nil];

NSExpression* expression =[NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"raise:toPower:" arguments:arrNum];

 NSLog(@"powerExp:%@",expression);

 int  resultSum = [[expression expressionValueWithObject:nil context: nil] intValue];
 NSLog(@"resultnum:%d",resultSum);`
```

I've got the output:

```
 powerExp:(2 + 4) ** 2

 resultnum:36
```